# Multivariate probit regression with random intercept in R

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I would like to analyse data having multiple dichotomous dependent variables and one categorical within-subject variable (with 3 levels) in R.

A multivariate probit regression with random intercept could be suited as far as I know. `mvProbit` could be used to specify a multivaraite probit regression, however I have no idea how to integreate a random intercept in this package for considering the repeated measurements of the independent variable.

Is there any way to specify the model in R?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).